# Dynamic query url order django

Tags: python, django, url-routing

Is there a way to match url to get result based on dynamic queries in Django without having to declare multiple urlpatterns. What I mean is the same urlpatterns to match something like

```
localhost:8000/person/?name=john&age=10&gender=male
localhost:8000/person/?age=10&gender=male&name=john
localhost:8000/person/?gender=male&name=john&age=10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing url [`GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) parameters with url [`regex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example) matching patterns.

According to your question, this url:

```
url(r'^person/', some_view, name='person'),
```

should match **all** the above urls.

Inside the `some_view` view, you can get each url `GET` parameter like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name', '')
    age = request.GET.get('age', '')
    gender = request.GET.get('gender', '')
    # return an Http Response (always)
```